# I there way to get contact icon placeholder from phone book or else in Android?

Tags: android

I need to retrieve contact placeholders with letters and colored background (Not photo just placeholder like in screenshot). Is there a way to get one from contacts or maybe through some google API?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm8pI.jpg

Comment: why do you want to use an api for this ? i'm sure you can quite easily create your own placeholders, pick a random color for the background and use the initials or whatever you want

Comment: My client wants to have exact same icons and placeholder like in contact book or like in Google account. I just wondering is there a way. if not I'll create it by myself.

Comment: ahh ok, i see, you basically want to pull through all the info

Comment: You might want to implement custom view in this case for example follow through this link https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable

Answer (score 0):

1. try this code

   ```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_circle_color"
            android:layout_width="50.0dip"
            android:layout_height="50.0dip"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_green"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_class_circle_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
   ```

In drawable -

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape android:shape="oval"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```